# Rewrite files after skipping lines batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, lines, skip

Need to read files in directory, rewrite them after skipping the first 77 lines, save to new txt file with the old name.
Diectory (there are many more files than this):

```
{1061A083-F913-4F7A-AEC4-E89BD7FEAC47}.html
{275A93DF-997B-4B2B-B5D6-C66302A03508}.html
{41579A2D-C022-44BE-9752-5407D241BBE2}.html
{47339F9D-AC59-433F-9FEB-1E818C7C1904}.html
{513E7E93-F6D5-4F1F-A905-28FE4D3DB30C}.html
```

Code I have so far:

```
for /f "skip=7 delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.html""') do (echo %%a>>newfile.txt)
xcopy newfile.txt C:\MBCNew\htmlFiles\Done\%%a.txt /y
del C:\MBCNew\htmlFiles\newfile.txt /f /q
```

Comment: You should change the `skip`  value from `7`   to `77`   .

Comment: I want to skip 77 lines not the 7 that is in the code. I was just testing on a smaller # of lines.

Comment: And does it work? What was the result? Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

The following simple batch script is very efficient (fast). It translates tab characters into spaces, but that should not be a problem for HTML.

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b *.html') do (
  more +77 "%%F" >"%%F.new"
  move /y "%%F.new" "%%F"
)
```